# how to Use updateActionButton twice in observeEvent

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am coding a Shiny App, which generates some plots upon pressing a button. The calculation starts when the user presses the butten, and I want to update the label of the button once it is pressed to show that the calculation is currently happening. After the calculation is finished, it should revert back to the "default" state. I thought this would be easy to do with `updateActionButton`, but somehow I cant get it to work. Here is a small reproducible example.

```
if (interactive()) {
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("update", "Do calculation"),
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$update, {
      # Change the button label
      updateActionButton(session, "update", label = "Running calculation")
      
      # This is a random calculation which takes a few seconds as a placeholder.
      result <- 0
      for (i in 1:5000000) {
        result <- result + sqrt(i)
      }
      
      updateActionButton(session, "update", label = "finished calculation") 
    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

It seems like it simply skips the first `updateActionButton` call...
Any insights into what I am doing wrong are much appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What is happening?

From `?updateActionButton`:

> The input updater functions send a message to the client, telling it to change the settings of an input object. **The messages are collected and sent after all the observers (including outputs) have finished running.**

This means that when you click on the button, the updates will only be sent once the `for` loop is done.

Since you're trying to update the label of the button twice, only the last update is sent to the client.

There are several solutions, I'm going to highlight the 2 easiest ones:

#### Solution 1

Set the `onclick` attribute of the button.

This way, you avoid requiring communication from the server for the UI to update. All the server needs to do is alert the client once it is done with the calculations.

[image: Solution 1 Demo]

```r
library(shiny)  
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(
    "update",
    "Do calculation",
    onclick = "$('#update').html('running...')"
  ),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$update, {
    # This is a random calculation which takes a few seconds as a placeholder.
    result <- 0
    for (i in 1:5000000) {
      result <- result + sqrt(i)
    }
    
    updateActionButton(session, "update", label = "finished calculation")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### Solution 2

Use `{shinyFeedback}`.

This way, you'll avoid writing ad-hoc inline js like in Solution 1 above. You'll also get a nice spinner on the button.

[image: Solution 2 demo]

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyFeedback)
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyFeedback(),
  loadingButton(
    inputId = "update",
    label = "Do calculation",
    loadingLabel = "running..."
  ),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$update, {
    # This is a random calculation which takes a few seconds as a placeholder.
    result <- 0
    for (i in 1:5000000) {
      result <- result + sqrt(i)
    }
    resetLoadingButton(inputId = "update")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### Edit: Usage with `renderPlot()`

I am adding this to address the OP's comment asking how you can use this approach when rendering plots.

All you need to do is to tell `renderPlot()` this: Once you're done plotting, reset the loading button. You can do this using `on.exit()`.

Here's a reprex:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyFeedback)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyFeedback(),
  loadingButton("renderButton", "Render Plot"),
  plotOutput("myPlot"),
  textOutput("renderStatus") #if i remove this, the code doesnt work
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$renderButton, {
    output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
      on.exit({
        resetLoadingButton(inputId = "renderButton")
      })
      # Your plotting code here
      plot(runif(100000), runif(100000), main = "New Plot") # random plot which takes  a few seconds to render
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, this is what I was looking for! 
I just realized that in my use case, this does not really work, because the data wrangling for my plots is pretty much instant, but the rendering of the plots takes a long time. So essentially its just in the "running" animation for 0.1 seconds and then the plots start to render. Do you by any chance know, if it is possible, to just let the "running" animation run for 1 second and then it turns into the default state? So that the plots render in the meantime

Comment: @nhaus Have a look at the last section of my updated answer on how to use the approach when rendering plots.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Mwavu, I managed to accomplish what I was trying. Although to be honest, I dont really understand why it works and would greatly appreciate if somebody could explain to me why it works.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  loadingButton("renderButton", "Render Plot"),
  plotOutput("myPlot"),
  textOutput("renderStatus") #if i remove this, the code doesnt work
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rendered <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$renderButton, {
    rendered(FALSE)  # Reset the rendered status
    output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
      # Your plotting code here
      plot(runif(100000), runif(100000), main = "New Plot") # random plot which takes  a few seconds to render
      rendered(TRUE)  # Mark the plot as rendered
    })
  })
  
  output$renderStatus <- reactive({ # <- if I remove the output$renderStatus the code doesnt work anymore (it is stuck in the "loading" annimation)
    if (rendered()) {
      resetLoadingButton(inputId = "renderButton")
    } 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Specifically, I do not understand why it is necessary to include the `textOutput("renderStatus")` and the `output$renderStatus`. I thought it should be enough to have this code block

```
reactive({ 
    if (rendered()) {
      resetLoadingButton(inputId = "renderButton")
    } 
  })
```

to trigger the default state of the button.